# Assertion failure after updating a smart contract with tables

Tags: smart-contract, table, c++

**Before the update**

Before the update of the code of my c++ smart contract, this uses to work absolutely fine. Data storing on the table and actions execution were done successfully.

**After the update**

After I updated the code - adding some functions and not touching the tables - it started showing this error:

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: read
pending console output:
```

**What I tried**

1. I tried to change the table names and execute the update code again (didn't work);
2. I tried to revert the contract to the exactly previous code (didn't work);
3. I tried to add `$NODEOSBINDIR/nodeos --verbose-http-errors true` to the script that starts the node (nothing more is shoed in the error output);
4. I tried to access the table after changing its name, and I could do it (but of course is empty).

**What I am looking for**

1. If anyone experienced the same issue please help to figure out more details
   about this `eosio_asser_message`;
2. A clear explanation on how to update smart contracts with tables and what happens in different use cases;
3. If I made some mistakes in the configuration of the flag `--verbose-http-errors true`.

Comment: Try to start `nodeos` with `--verbose-http-errors` flag and see if there is a more detailed error log.

Comment: I already tried, and this command is already in both the config.ini and the script to start the node; but I cannot see any difference in the error output.

Comment: But are you able to access the table using `cleos`?

Comment: I can access the table, but there is no content inside. The previous content - of the old table before renaming - is no more there.

Comment: I think you should post some code smippets you have changed to get mor help...

Comment: But actually I just updated the code and reverted it to the initial working status. It is really strange that it is not working anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83939/discussion-between-damianodamiano-and-riccardo-persiani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but I finally solved the issue.

Searching on Google for this kind of error, the most interesting source I was able to find was the following: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4394.

The issue described at the link is not the same as mine, but actually suggested me that there was **something wrong when calling an action**, from a smart contract.

In fact, the error was in the parameters that I was passing, which where not matching with the action called.